# FileMaker not prompting for Login

Tags: filemaker

So I moved a FileMaker database from a machine with FM server 10 to a new machine with FM server 11.

Everything seems to be working, but the problem is it no longer prompts users for a user name and password.  It seems to just log them in automatically with their windows user name.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: My FileMaker consultant thinks it's a bug in FileMaker server 11 v1.  He says if I have a fileMaker account first in the login list then it should always prompt for a login.  I guess if you only have external accounts set up then it's normal behavior to pass through the windows credentials?

Comment: Are you working on Macs?  It sounds like you've added the FM login to your keychain so it automatically logs in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you activated external authentication on the FileMaker Server. That means that FileMaker server will try to auth using using an Active Directory or even local windows accounts on the server machine.

Look in the FileMaker Server Admin Console is you enabled External Authentication, if so, deactivate it and restart the FileMaker Service.